# How to include AWS service error codes in a third party project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I am developing a module which internally uses AWS Java SDK client to make EC2 related API calls.

E.g. I have a requirement where I need to attach ENIs to my instance. One of the possible error code in this api call is `AttachmentLimitExceeded`, I want to execute another logic if this particular error is thrown. I know I can retrieve this error code using `AmazonServiceException.getErrorCode()` method. But is there any jar which includes all the possible error code strings or exception classes which I can use to handle such error codes and lets say have a switch case depending on each error code?

I **do not** want to do a hardcoded string matching like

```
AmazonServiceException.getErrorCode().equals("AttachmentLimitExceeded");
```

Since this code will need changes as and when AWS changes their error codes. What is the standard way of including these [error codes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html#CommonErrors) in third party project?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is no such standard way of handling these error codes.

It depends a lot on the service you use. For example, the mentioned `AttachmentLimitExceeded` error code appears in the [`AWSSupportClient`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-support/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/support/AWSSupportClient.java#L153-L155) with the underlying [`AttachmentLimitExceededException`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-support/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/support/model/AttachmentLimitExceededException.java), so you can catch it if you're using, for example, [`addAttachmentsToSet`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-support/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/support/AWSSupport.java#L179-L180) method from this service.

But unfortunately, [`AmazonEC2Client`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-ec2/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.java) doesn't define such specific exceptions (see the link to the code and compare to the `AWSSupportClient` above for the evidence). It only has the [`AmazonEC2Exception`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/AmazonEC2Exception.html) with [`getErrorCode`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException.html#getErrorCode--) returning `String`.

Another example of a client with predefined specific exceptions is the [`AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-ssm/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simplesystemsmanagement/AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java#L233-L325). Look at the subclasses of the [`AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simplesystemsmanagement/model/AWSSimpleSystemsManagementException.html).

---

So the bottom line is that if the service you're interested in doesn't define specific exceptions for different error types, you can

- either use the `getErrorCode` method as you mentioned, which is understandably undesirable
- or not rely on the error codes at all

The choice is tough, but probably you can overcome the problem by configuring some custom request retry policy.